# Django ImportError: cannot import name 'ModelForm'

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-forms

[image: I have fixed the error from given question and now I am getting an error on command promp]

I am pretty much new for Django and trying to create fields to add a new movie to the existing model. It shows an error : ImportError: cannot import name 'ModelForm'

```
#forms.py file: 
from django import forms
from django import ModelForm
from .models import Movie


class MovieForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Movie
        fields = ['genre', 'price', 'rent_time', 'flag']
   

class CustForm(forms.Form):
    f_name = forms.CharField(label='First_Name', max_length=50)
    l_name = forms.CharField(label='Last_Name', max_length=50)
    address = forms.CharField(label='Address', max_length=125)
    cell = forms.IntegerField(label='Cell')
#------------------------------------------------------------------------
#models.py file:
from django.db import models
from django.forms import ModelForm


class Customer(models.Model):
    f_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    l_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=125)
    cell = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)


class Movie(models.Model):
    genre = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    price = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    rent_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True)
    flag = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    user_id = models.ForeignKey('Customer', on_delete=models.SET_NULL,         
null=True)
#------------------------------------------------------------------------
#views.py file:
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Customer, Movie
# from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from .forms import MovieForm, CustForm


def dashboard(request):
    customer_data = Customer.objects.all()
    context = {'Customer_List': customer_data}
    return render(request, 'movie_renting_app/home.html', context)


def movie_list(request):
    movie_data = Movie.objects.all()
    context = {"Movie_List": movie_data}
    return render(request, 'movie_renting_app/all_movies.html', context)


def rented_movies(request):
    rented_movie = Movie.objects.filter(flag=True)
    context = {"Rented_Movies_List": rented_movie}
    return render(request, 'movie_renting_app/rent.html', context)


def add_movies(request):
    if request.POST:
        form = MovieForm()
        print(request)
        # return movie_list(request)
    else:
        form = MovieForm()
        return render(request, 'movie_renting_app/new_movie.html',             
{'form': form})


def add_customer(request):
    if request.POST:
        form = request.POST
        print(request)
        c = Customer(f_name=form['f_name'], l_name=form['l_name'],     
address=form['address'], cell=form['cell'])
        c.save()
        return dashboard(request)
    else:
        form = CustForm()
        return render(request, 'movie_renting_app/new_customer.html', 
{'form': form})

def update_customer_info(request):
    pass


def available_list(request):
    pass
```

I am getting an error on command prompt.
I have no clue what is going wrong with my code. I have tried various ways to import the ModelForm but it showing me the same error message. I am using Django 2.0 and Python 3.6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is probably your second line in forms.py. `ModelForm` is in `django.forms`, and can't be imported from `django`. Try this instead:

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
```

Or, change `class MovieForm(ModelForm):` to `class MovieForm(forms.ModelForm):` and remove your `ModelForm` import line.

Comment: I have made changes according to your suggestions. Can you please help me with above command prompt error

Answer (score 3):

ModelForm class is located in Django forms
so you can import it as shown below.

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
```

or use it directly when subclassing your form class

```
class CustomForm(forms.ModelForm):
    # your form fields here
    pass
```

for more information about ModelForms see [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/forms/modelforms/)

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Comment: I have made changes according to your suggestions. Can you please help me with above command prompt error

Comment: if am getting you well the issue might be on migrations. please delete the migration files in the migration directory and the SQLite file too. then try to make migrations again

Comment: Thanks for an update. I have solved the problem in the same way.

Answer (score 0):

Replace this wrong code in **line 2, "forms.py"**:

```py
from django import ModelForm # Line 2, "forms.py"
```

With this correct code:

```py
from django.forms import ModelForm # Line 2, "forms.py"
```